# Is there a way to use stop order and trailing stop at the same time?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I am trying to use stop order for a specific price (or preferred percentile loss rate) and a trailing stop order at the same time, but if I run the code with both of the order types only one of them (depends the code I use sometimes I get results for only stop order or sometimes I get results for only trailing stop) gives results properly.

I found a solution about running the code with both of them but this time stop-loss order waits for candle close (if I choose low value of the candle code does not give any results about stop loss), so it may cause more loss than I specified.

Current code I use for stop-loss and trail stop are below.

```
stop_loss_ratio = input.float(title = "Stop loss Ratio", minval = 0.0, step = 0.1, defval = 1) * 0.01
strategy.entry('Long1', strategy.long, when=bull1 and (dayofmonth > 7), alert_message='Open Long1 (Monthly) Position')
entry_price_long = strategy.opentrades > 0 ? (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)) : na
stop_loss_price_long = entry_price_long * (1 - stop_loss_ratio)
entry_price_short = strategy.opentrades < 0 ? (strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)) : na
stop_loss_price_short = entry_price_short * (1 + stop_loss_ratio)
strategy.close('Long1', when= close < stop_loss_price_long, comment = 'Stop Loss Long1')
trailStop = input.float(title='Trailing Stop (%)', minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1.4) * 0.01
longStopPrice = 0.0
shortStopPrice = 0.0
longStopPrice := if strategy.position_size > 0
    stopValue = close * (1 - trailStop)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0
shortStopPrice := if strategy.position_size < 0
    stopValue = close * (1 + trailStop)
    math.min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    99999
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id='Trailing Stop', stop=longStopPrice, alert_message='Close by Trailing Stop (Weekly) Position')
```

Comment: You can specify stop & trailing parameters simultaneously in one `strategy.exit()` call

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.